# Android - Show Custom Notification without default notification- Parse.com

Tags: android, notifications, parse-platform, push

Does exist a different way to send a push without show default notification (from Parse library)?

I've created a custom BroadcastReceiver to show notification with full message, but if I send json with "alert" parameter, the default notification is shown by Parse library.

For example:

> { "alert": "Both notifications will be shown", "url": "www.parse.com", "action" : "com.myapp.package.UPDATE_STATUS" }

and

> { "message": "Custom notification will be shown", "url": "www.parse.com", "action" : "com.myapp.package.UPDATE_STATUS" }

The first json shows default notification, because Parse library intercepts the "alert" parameter. The seconds json shows just my custom notification.

The second json would be perfect, but I send push notifications to iOS app too. So, I want to have the same json for Android and iOS. I want to send just one push.

Is it possible to use "alert" parameter and show only custom notification?

Thank you!!
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, replace :

```
PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, YourActivity.class);
```

to :

```
PushService.startServiceIfRequired(this);
```

Parse BroadcastReceiver no longer receive notifications.

https://www.parse.com/questions/how-suppress-push-notification-from-being-displayed